# Clearing and updating svg on click

Tags: javascript, d3.js

From the bl.ocks [here](https://blockbuilder.org/pybern/4b4b73dbd47ec40e3b5ca7971dce1a36), I am attempting to assign an on-click button that:

1. Removes the current shapes, hopefully by a smooth transition.
2. Depending on button click, returns the selected visual.

Even if it is on the same visual, it will remove and reload the same one. The transition I am hoping to get is found [here](https://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/9b3fc45d5c1d3af7e53daef7df28ac11/e25d1478fc2899a402e1dbfaad2090df6b012804) but triggered with a click rather than a random interval.

I have tried a bunch of different ways without much results, my current attempt is to `remove` the current `rects` before calling my `squared` function like below:

```
function remove(){
  d3.selectAll("rect").transition().remove();
};

d3.selectAll(".button1").on("click", function animate(){
          option = +this.value;
          remove();
          square(data[option]);
          console.log('b');
                });
```

Earlier I thought what I needed was to update twice, the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55353309/update-exit-update-enter-patterns-with-transition) (my earlier question) addressed the part where it goes back to 0 (also the creator) of the bl.ocks above, but I cannot seem to wrap my head around how to call 2 different functions to clear first and then update with a button click event.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the remove function as follows:

```
function remove() {
  var cellUpdate = cell.selectAll("rect")
  const length = cell.selectAll("rect").data().length

  var cellExit = cellUpdate.transition()
    .delay(function(d, i) { return (length - i) * 7; })
    .duration(updateDuration)
    .attr("width", 0)
    .remove();
}
```

`cellUpdate` is the selection of the cells that you want to remove. The `length` can be retrieved from the number of data elements or the number of nodes in the group (for the example `data()` was used). After the selection is retrieved you can apply the desired transition with delayed duration on it `width`, `opacity` etc.

Here is a sample block that allows you to achieve the desired goal: https://blockbuilder.org/cstefanache/e3110f130394eb71b9adfb5060ef2b78